# Custom string formatters

Tags: c#, strings, formatting

Some time ago I was experimenting with an [Extendable format provider](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131222/extendable-format-provider) but I wasn't satisfied with the implementation. It didn't feal very *SOLID* so I've rewritten it to this:

The base class is the `Formatter`:

```
public abstract class Formatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    protected Formatter(CultureInfo culture = null)
    {
        Culture = culture ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    }

    public static Formatter Default(CultureInfo culture = null) => new CompositeFormatter(culture);

    public CultureInfo Culture { get; }

    public virtual object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        // null means use the default .net formatter
        return formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
    }
    public abstract string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider);
}
```

It supports culture info and by default the invariant culture. As we already have to implement the `Format` method I didn't want to create another one like `TryFormat` and if the formatting didn't work I return `null`... but maybe I should have go the `TryFormat` way?

As an example here are three formatters:

```
public class DecimalColorFormatter : Formatter
{
    public override string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (!(arg is Color))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var color = (Color)arg;
        var argb = color.ToArgb();

        if (format.Equals("rgb-dec", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return String.Format(Culture, "({0},{1},{2})", color.R, color.G, color.B);
        }

        if (format.Equals("argb-dec", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return String.Format(Culture, "({0},{1},{2},{3})", color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class HexadecimalColorFormatter : Formatter
{
    public override string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (!(arg is Color))
        {            
            return null;
        }

        var color = (Color)arg;
        var argb = color.ToArgb();

        if (format.Equals("rgb-hex", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            return String.Format(Culture, "#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", color.R, color.G, color.B);
        }

        if (format.Equals("argb-hex", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return String.Format(Culture, "#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}", color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class CaseFormatter : Formatter
{
    public override string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        switch (format)
        {
            case "U": return arg.ToString().ToUpper();
            case "L": return arg.ToString().ToLower();
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I compose the formatter with this two helpers:

```
public class CompositeFormatter : Formatter
{
    private Formatter[] _formatters;

    public CompositeFormatter(CultureInfo culture, params Formatter[] formatters) : base(culture)
    {
        _formatters = formatters;
    }

    public CompositeFormatter(params Formatter[] formatters)
    : this((CultureInfo)null, formatters)
    { }

    public override string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        foreach (var formatter in _formatters)
        {
            var result = formatter.Format(format, arg, formatProvider);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public static class FormatterComposer
{
    public static Formatter Add<T>(this Formatter formatter, CultureInfo culture = null)
    where T : Formatter, new()
    {
        return new CompositeFormatter(culture, formatter, new T());
    }
}
```

---

Examples:

```
var formatter = Formatter.Default()
    .Add<DecimalColorFormatter>()
    .Add<HexadecimalColorFormatter>()
    .Add<CaseFormatter>();


string.Format(formatter, "{0:U} = {0:rgb-hex} or {0:rgb-dec}", Color.Aquamarine);
string.Format(formatter, "{0:L} = {0:argb-hex} or {0:argb-dec}", Color.Aquamarine);
string.Format(formatter, "{0} = {0:argb-hex}", (string)null);
```

results:

```
COLOR [AQUAMARINE] = #7FFFD4 or (127,255,212)
color [aquamarine] = #FF7FFFD4 or (255,127,255,212)
 =
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unused variables**

First of all, there are `argb`variables in your code which are not used, so let`s remove them.

**Type keywords**

Secondly you use String class specifier instead of string, while the second one is strongly suggested by Microsoft. I would have changed that for your code to be consistent with code of other .NET developers.

**Unnecessary constructor**

Thirdly, if you use default parameters like this in the first constructor of `CompositeFormatter`

```
public CompositeFormatter(CultureInfo culture = null, params Formatter[] formatters) : base(culture)
{
    _formatters = formatters;
}
```

then you have no need for second one and it can be removed.

**Creation of not required objects**

Fourthly, your `Add<T>` extension create new instance of `CompositeFormatter` every time and they are kept in memory which is not a good practice. And the execution travels through a lot of objects because of this.

So what we can do is rewrite `Formatter[] _formatters` to `List<Formatter>`.
Then in constructor `_formatters = formatters.ToList()`.
Later we can add next method to `CompositeFormatter`

```
public void Add(Formatter formatter)
{
    _formatters.Add(formatter);
}
```

Finally, we can rewrite your extension like this

```
public static Formatter Add<T>(this Formatter formatter, CultureInfo culture = null)
    where T : Formatter, new()
{
    var newFormatter = new T();
    var compositeFormatter = formatter as CompositeFormatter;
    if (compositeFormatter == null)
    {
        return new CompositeFormatter(culture, formatter, newFormatter);
    }
    compositeFormatter.Add(newFormatter);
    return compositeFormatter;
}
```

**Few final notes.**

Your `_formatters` should be marked as `readonly` since you are only assigning value to it in the constructor.

Make classes that are not intended for inheritance `sealed` not only because it improves the code style and prevents design flaws but also because it improves performance.

Best regards :)

Comment: I agree with everything but one thing, the `formatter as CompositeFormatter` this is not allowed in a SOLID design. The `Formatter` must not depend on the `CompositeFormatter` which is only a _helper_ that supports the _Composite Pattern_. I've been also thinking about it and came to the conclusion that it makes sense to let it be the way it is ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t, is it not allowed? Extensions are not actually extending classes and are not parts of their functionality. It is just a syntax sugar C# provides us with. Therefore, as I see it, `Formatter` does not depend upon `CompositeFormatter`. Rather this method depends upon both:)
Am I mistaken?

Comment: Ooops, no, you're right. It's an extension, so it actually doesn't matter. I thought somehow it was the constructor, sorry ;-]

Comment: You should probably handle the case when the `formatter` parameter in the `Add` extension method is itself a `CompositeFormatter`. Otherwise you'll still have cases where it would be possible to create deeply nested composite classes unnecessarily. For that, you'd probably need to expose the formatters in `CompositeFormatter` as a collection so that you can combine composites into a single composite.